# Maven "also-make"'s behavior

Tags: maven, maven-3

Let's suppose there are two projects, A and B, and B has a dependency on A.
Then I write
`mvn verify --also-make --projects "B"`
Maven help claims that `also-make` build projects required, so project `A` will be built.
But what does "build" mean? What maven phase will be applied to project `A`? `Compile`, `verify` or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will apply the command or phase that you gave in the Maven command.

Comment: So if you specify 'verify' it will not install project A in the local maven repo, so the unit tests for project B will still use the old version of project A?

Comment: It will not install the version, but AFAIK still use the new version from the other build.